# change a bitmap to other bitmap in android canvas

Tags: android, bitmap

Is there any Android method that allows to change/switch a bitmap to other bitmap? I do some researches but can't find any info about it; so I have written a customized method for that purpose.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    // Get the Cell's position.
    selX = (int)((event.getX()) / wCell);
    selY = (int)((event.getY() - hCell) / wCell);

    if( selX > BSIZE || selY > BSIZE || selY < 0) { 
        return false;
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "selX: " + selX + " selY: " + selY);
        cellSelection(selX, selY);
    }
    return true;    
}

/** Change the bitmap image when it's touched. */
private void cellSelection( int x, int y) {
    if(this.touch == true) {
        this.canvas.drawBitmap(bmap1, 0, 0, null);
    } else {
        this.canvas.drawBitmap(bmap2, 0, 0, null);
    }
    invalidate();
}
```

But I keep getting NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION whenever the code hit to this line: this.canvas.drawBitmap().

Comment: Where are you defining/initializing `canvas`?

Comment: you must check initialization of `Canvas` and `bmap1` and `bmap2` objects..

Comment: I define the canvas in onDraw(Canvas canvas), this.canvas = canvas. And define bmap1 and bmap2 in the constructor of the class. The problem that I am encountering is everything works fine as long as I don't touch the bmap2 on the screen. Whenever I touch the bmap2 (to change to bmap1), I got the exception error.

Answer (score 0):

Put the drawing code in onDraw(), set touch to true in onTouch().